# How to get rid of the 3838 port number in the address of Shiny app

Tags: shiny, digital-ocean, shiny-server

I am struggling to get rid of the Port number 3838 when I host my Shiny app in DigitalOcean.

So far I have consulted with below 2 links, however nothing works for me:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-server-series-part-2-running-shiny-on-multiple-ports/
https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/#shiny-user-perms

I have xampp as my web server which currently listens to 80, whereas shiny to 3838.
When I put http://ip-address:3838 in the address bar, my Shiny app is working fine. However when I put http://ip-address/shiny/, it is not.

Below is my shiny config file

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /opt/lampp/htdocs/My_App;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

And, below is some relevant part from xampp.conf file :

```
# demo for mod_perl responsehandler
#PerlModule Apache::CurrentTime
#<Location /time>
#      SetHandler modperl
#      PerlResponseHandler Apache::CurrentTime
#</Location>

location /shiny/ {
  proxy_pass http://139.59.42.170/:3838/;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

I want my Shiny app should work when I put http://ip-address/shiny/, in the address bar. I would appreciate if someone can point me what is the right approach to achieve the same.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you have an extra backslash in `proxy_pass`. Try this: `proxy_pass http://139.59.42.170:3838/` and then restart nginx

Comment: @ blondeclover - I am not using nginx. I am using xampp. I have tried with http://139.59.42.170:3838/ which doesnt work

Comment: I think your code is based on [a nginx reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). If you're using xampp, you'll need to write the reverse proxy in the xampp format. Maybe something like this: http://gyanmoti.in/2016/07/reverse-proxy-config-in-apache-xampp/

Comment: @ blondeclover - it is working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: great! I'm happy to hear it. Will you post your solution as an answer? Then if others have the same problem in the future, they'll get help from your work!